# negative values for AIC and BIC

Tags: goodness-of-fit, aic, bic, gumbel-distribution

I am trying to fit a gumbel distribution using MLE for the following 10 data points.
`DATA=(3.62,3.76,3.57,3.56,3.61,3.77,3.46,3.6,3.39,3.74)`

The problem is that the information criteria have negative values
AIC = -8.67816
BIC = -8.07299
Negative Log-Likelihood Value:  -6.33908

The reason why I selected a gumbel model is that it's a commonly accepted probability model for the application.

Questions

1-Are negative values for AIC BIC possible and what does it indicate?

2-Is 10 a sufficient sample size for estimation of Gumbel distribution parameters to conclude that one model is better than another?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the AIC, BIC is negative. 10 is a small sample size in any application. Report the parameter estimates and confidence intervals. You most likely won't conclude that your model is "better" than one trained on a larger sample size.

Comment: True and agreed. Can you elaborate on the methods/suggestions/guidelines for minimum number of samples to indicate sufficiency. What i mean is that is there a methods/indicator that my model is trained through sufficient data.

Comment: Unfortunately no. You would have to prespecify such objectives. Model selection by AIC in practice is often a simple comparison: you choose the model with smallest AIC. When comparing two models, $n=10$ is going to pick *one* as the smaller, but your issue is quantifying the uncertainty of the decision since you know $n=100$ would give a more reliable selection. In classical hypothesis testing, reporting the power and the $p$-value do this. In Bayes one uses decision theory.

Comment: If the other model is Gumbel, you may as well attempt a hypothesis test for the true parameter values.